# Blazor Razor component create pdf download link

Tags: c#, blazor

I have been butting my head on this for a few days now and cant figure it out. How do I create a download link in a Blazor Razor component with a local file url for a pdf.

```
@code {
string noteContent;
string fileName = "note.txt";

string path = @"E:\Attachments\test.txt";
Uri myUri = new Uri(@"E:\Attachments\test.txt");

public async void DownloadFile()
{
    //await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>(
    //    "FileSaveAs",
    //    fileName,
    //    noteContent
    //);

   await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>(
   "downloadURI",
   myUri,
   "test.txt"
      );
    }
 }
```

and js file

```
function FileSaveAs(filename, fileContent) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = filename;
    link.href = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + 
    encodeURIComponent(fileContent)
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}

function downloadURI(uri, name) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;enter code here
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] of your progress so far? Showing what you have tried?

Comment: How will the Blazor component know the path to a local file?

Comment: I have tried using JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>. but failed so many times I just ended up deleting everything out of frustration :( 

Im getting the url from list obj in the razor component based on a selection the user makes. So I have the url as a string ready to go.

Comment: If you are still looking for a solution, please find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73567348/6038249).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample JS Interop function that gives the end user the download prompts:

```
    window.saveFile = function (bytesBase64, mimeType, fileName) {
        var fileUrl = "data:" + mimeType + ";base64," + bytesBase64;
        fetch(fileUrl)
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(blob => {
                var link = window.document.createElement("a");
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob, { type: mimeType });
                link.download = fileName;
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            });
    }
```

Here's how I call it from the Blazor app:

```
        public static void Save(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, byte[] byteData, string mimeType, string fileName)
        {
            if (byteData == null)
            {
                jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "The byte array provided for Exporting was Null.");
            }
            else
            {
                jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("saveFile", Convert.ToBase64String(byteData), mimeType, fileName);
            }
        }
```

What's left in this is to obtain your `byte[]` from the file. How you do that will depend on your use case and app, here are a couple of common cases:

- in a server-side Blazor app, your C# already runs on the server, so you can inject an `IWebHostEnvironment` and get the webroot path from it to access your file - something like `var path = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + \\myfile.txt` and then just read from that path. THen call the JS Interop
- in  WASM app, you don't have a file system. So, you need to have that data in memory - whether you got it from a file selector, or from some WebAPI endpoint, or even generated it in C#, is up to the particular use case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Just one question what should I pass into the jsRuntime in the Save function call?

Comment: An instance of the Blazor JS Runtime, you get it through DI, something like this in the comonent: `@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime;`

Comment: You may also find this helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Awesome thank you. Will test. Thank you so much for taking the time to help

Comment: Great! You could accept the answer to help other people looking for such a sample