# How to download PDF file (not view) using Blazor WASM from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blazor-webassembly

I have PDF files stored in Azure Blob storage and I would like to allow users to click a button and download the pdf file to their computer instead of opening them in the browser.

My current thinking is to use the solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61055985/blazor-razor-component-create-pdf-download-link) that uses javascript interop to call a function that takes a base64 byte array. My problem is how do I get a base64 byte array directly from Azure blob without having to save the file to my server first.

If you have any other ways of downloading a PDF please share.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to make use of blob's `content-disposition` property.

If you want to **always** download the blob, then you can set the `content-disposition` property of the blob to something like `attachment; filename="filename.pdf"`. This way when a user clicks on the blob URL, it will always be downloaded. For this, the blob must be publicly accessible.

Other option would be to create a `Shared Access Signature` on the blob with `Read` permission and you would override `Content-Disposition` header in the the SAS token. You will give the SAS URL to your application and on the click of the button you will open this SAS URL which will download the blob.

I wrote a blog post about it long time back that you may find useful: https://gauravmantri.com/2013/11/28/new-changes-to-windows-azure-storage-a-perfect-thanksgiving-gift/.