# How can I open a pdf in a new tab with Blazor

Tags: pdf, blazor, netlify

The following code should work with plain html

```
<a href="pdf/foo.pdf" target="_blank">Open pdf</a>
```

It also works with Blazor (WebAssembly) but only from localhost. A new tab is opened with address `https://localhost:[...]/pdf/foo.pdf`. In production, the browser tries to open `https://[...]/pdf/foo.pdf` and I get the error

> Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

Is there a solution for Blazor?

#### Edit 2

I deleted my first edit, because with the following new information, I think it is not relevant anymore.
Since I thought, it was a problem with deploying pdfs on netlify, I asked in their forum: https://answers.netlify.com/t/how-can-i-deploy-a-pdf/54897. (Sorry, the short links syntax [][] does not seem to work in edits.) I created a demo page (https://beautiful-snickerdoodle-bb5389.netlify.app/) and found out, it is not working on my PC and several laptops, but on my smartphone. A user in the netlify forum was able to display the pdf in Chrome but not Safari. So, I think, it is not a problem with netlify but there is something wrong with my page. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Deploy the missing pdf to the server.

Comment: @Yogi: Please so my edit above.

Comment: Is this Blazor Wasm standalone or have you deployed an asp.net server?  I can see the PDF is there but your app intercepts the URL.

Comment: It is standalone (I think). Why does it work on some devices and on some it does not? How can I fix this?

Comment: It 'works' when you load the complete pdf url in a fresh browser. Once you run the app it will stop doing so. I have a suggestion, just a minute.

Comment: I can confirm this: Open pdf after I completely set back Firefox is possible. After running the app, it does not work anymore.

Comment: I have a possible solution to show a pdf file but using memory stream (you can show the pdf without saving it on the server) so if you get that pdf from the databaqse for example it could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

What works in "normal" HTML, does not work in Blazor, because the service-worker routes unknown routes to index.html. See `onFetch()` method of service-worker.published.js:

```
const shouldServeIndexHtml = event.request.mode === 'navigate';
const request = shouldServeIndexHtml ? 'index.html' : event.request;
```

When I click the link `<a href="pdf/foo.pdf" target="_blank">Open pdf</a>`, the `shouldServeIndexHtml` is `true`.

To avoid this, I changed above code to

```
const shouldServeIndexHtml = event.request.mode === 'navigate'
     && !event.request.url.includes('/pdf/');
const request = shouldServeIndexHtml ? 'index.html' : event.request;
```

This works, because my pdfs are in a subfolder "pdf" under wwwroot. Since the url includes "/pdf/", the `shouldServeIndexHtml` becomes `false` and the pdf is displayed. Please find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#support-server-rendered-pages).

Answer (score 1):

How you serve a download is your choice, how it is handled is the users choice,

[image]

there are two recommended methods,

1. offer `<a href="absolute fab.pdf" download>download this fab pdf, I promise its safe to run</a>`
2. If you cant see anything in this blank iFrame your browsers exploit security is perfect.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. Do you mean, I must add `download` to the `<a>` element? Then, this must be a Blazor thing, because there are pages out there without `download` and therefore, for me, it is not the expected behavior. I reset Edge, added `download` to the first link on my demo page and clicked the link. The pdf was downloaded without asking me to open or download it. This is even the case, when I set Edge as default pdf app and toggle the "Always download PDF files" option under Settings > Site permissions > PDF documents.

Comment: The point about user settings/options is correct but not the issue here. The pdf url is never reached by the Browser.

Comment: Please excuse my late reply. I was on vacation for a couple of days. I updated my demo page with four simple links: with fixed and relative paths and with and without `download`. The links with `download` work but both links without `download` do not, even the one with fixed address. Tested in Chrome, Edge, Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Your path to "pdf/foo.pdf" denotes that there is a pdf folder in wwwroot folder of your website, make sure this folder also exists in your prod environment and has pdf file you are trying to open, also make sure this folder has read/write rights for IIS_IUSRS